# Rails 3: How to get today's date in specific timezone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date, timezone

To get today's date I do:

```
Date.today    # => Fri, 20 May 2011
```

I would like to get today's date in a specific timezone, say `'Melbourne'`.

I have the following setting in my `application.rb`:

```
config.time_zone = 'Melbourne'
```

and I set:

```
Time.zone = 'Melbourne'
```

in my application controller before each action.

However, it doesn't help (I guess because these settings affects only dates that are stored in the database).

How could I get today's date in `'Melbourne'` ?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You should be able to do this: `Time.current`. That would display the current time in Melbourne if that's what `Time.zone` is set to.

Comment: `Time.zone.now.to_date` is the most elegant! Thanks!

Comment: `Time.current.to_date` is even better !

Comment: Even better for any Date object: Date.today.to_time_in_current_zone

Comment: @SlobodanKovacevic Date.today.to_time_in_current_zone returns a Time object NOT a Date object.

Comment: What's nice as well is you can do `Time.zone.to_date.midnight + some.hours` to get whatever time of day you like!

Comment: @Ziggy: `Time.current.beginning_of_day + 18.hours` will work too :)

Answer (score 85):

`Date` objects don't necessarily have timezones, but `Time` objects do. You can try it as a `Time`, then convert back to a `Date`:

```
Time.now.to_date
# => Thu, 19 May 2011 
Time.now.in_time_zone('Melbourne').to_date
# => Fri, 20 May 2011
```

Answer (score 47):

### [`Date.current`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Date/current/class)

[`Date.current`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Date/current/class) is probably the most clear and succinct way, and was added in Rails 3.

```
$ Date.current
#=> Sat, 14 Jul 2018
```

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Date/current/class

Answer (score 21):

If you want to get "today" in some specified time zone without having to change `Time.zone`, I would do something like fl00r and Dylan Markow suggested:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone('Melbourne').to_date
```

or this:

```
Time.find_zone!('Melbourne').today
```

I wrote a little helper method `Date.today_in_zone` that makes getting a "today" `Date` for a time zone even easier:

```
 # Defaults to using Time.zone
 > Date.today_in_zone
=> Fri, 26 Oct 2012

 # Or specify a zone to use
 > Date.today_in_zone('Melbourne')
=> Sat, 27 Oct 2012
```

I think it reads a little nicer than `Time.find_zone!('Melbourne').today`...

To use it, just throw this in a file like `'lib/date_extensions.rb'` and `require 'date_extensions'`.

```
class Date
  def self.today_in_zone(zone = ::Time.zone)
    ::Time.find_zone!(zone).today
  end
end
```

Answer (score 14):

It seems `Time.zone.today` also works.

Answer (score 9):

use `DateTime` class

```
DateTime.now.in_time_zone 'Melbourne'
```

Comment: That's a nice, concise way to do it that I hadn't seen before. It looks like  Time.now.in_time_zone 'Melbourne'  will also work.

Comment: This should be upvoted waaay more. Clear, succinct, works with dates, doesn't require ActiveSupport, and doesn't involve any mucking about in config settings.

Answer (score 3):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :004 > Time.now
 => 2011-05-19 15:46:45 +0100 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :006 > Time.now.in_time_zone('Melbourne')
 => Fri, 20 May 2011 00:47:00 EST +10:00 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :007 > Time.now.in_time_zone('Melbourne').to_date
 => Fri, 20 May 2011
```

Answer (score 2):

For valid timezone names, checkout: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 3 you can simply do this by calling to_time_in_current_zone on a Date object.

```
Date.today.to_time_in_current_zone
```

Comment: If the server time is different than the Rails time zone, `Date.today ` might return yesterday's or tomorrow's date. Calling `to_time_in_current_zone` will then make it into a time in the Rails zone, but a time that might be yesterday or tomorrow. This is useful if you have a date known to be in the correct time zone, as from `Time.zone.today`, but misleading with `Date.today`.