# Rails - Setting time_zone dynamically as per user selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I appreciate your help one of the features working on for my new website!

This is regarding the dynamic time_zones as per the requirement user would be able to choose from set of pre-defined time_zones say us_zones. When the user picks the zone the entire site should be set/updated to TimeZone.

However, at present the new time zone is not becoming updated into Apache and the updation of time zone happens only at the restart of the server.

I was thinking in the lines of using Rails Initializer class and initialize_time_zone() methods, but even this requires the rails server to be restarted.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place to Application controller something like this:

```
def set_api_time_zone
  utc_offset = current_user_session && current_user_session.user ? current_user_session.user.time_zone_offset.to_i.minutes : 0
  user_timezone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[utc_offset]
  Time.zone = user_timezone if user_timezone
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, will be using the similar one, however instead of offset I would go with using TimeZone as such DateTime.now.in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)') as suggested  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060436/rails-3-how-to-get-todays-date-in-specific-timezone) I have pre-defined time zone