# Rails datetime_select start time greater than users zone time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, timezone, ruby-on-rails-5

[image]

Hi! So, I have a rails app which has a `<%= f.datetime_select :ends_at %>` field in a create bid form. I want the start time to be the user's current time but allow other users to see the ends_at in their own time zone once this bid is created.

So I need help in two aspects:

*1. How to set the select drop down to show time greater than Time.now for the user's current time zone, and whether to use Time.now or Time.zone.now?

*2. How to change the ends_at with respect to user's time zone viewing the record ?

Will really appreciate!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices.

1. Set the timezone for the application in the `application.rb` file.   This will force all times presented to be in that timezone.   **This will only work if your users are in a single timezone.**
2. Store a users timezone, and change the timezone per request using an around_filter in your rails controller. As suggested by [Rails - Setting time_zone dynamically as per user selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800301/rails-setting-time-zone-dynamically-as-per-user-selection)

**For Background**

`Time.zone.now` is only going to convert the timestamp to the timezone that the Rails environment is currently in.  Which is always UTC unless otherwise specified.

`Time.now` will always return the system time.

If you are behind UTC say -05:00 that time will always look ahead.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting [`Time.zone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-zone-3D) in the controller, which sets the time zone for the current request/thread.

You can also persist user’s time zone, and do something like:

`Time.zone = current_user.time_zone`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks! :)
I solved the problem by:

1. First of all changing the default time zone to Central Time.
2. Then Added a new column in devise as time_zone, which user specified
   as per his time zone
3. Added an around filter in application controller to ensure times are
   changed for a user:

   class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
        around_filter :user_time_zone, if: :current_user

   ```
     private

     def user_time_zone(&block)
       Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone, &block)
     end
   ```

   end

Found a good video by Ryan Bates: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-1ISHNEB9U
after using your suggestions and researching more.